# Sql query for parent child records

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child

I need to find out final parent record for each child with a recursive logic until I find parent as null e.g. child=12 has final parent equal to 7 .
So as we traverse to find final parent all the non null values for L1, L2 and L3 will be populated in child record.
May I get some guidance what SQL function I should use to generate following output.

Input:

```
Child Parent  L1   L2   L3
12    435     xyz
435    7      xyz  abc  def
7     Null    xyz
```

Output:

```
 Child    L1   L2   L3
     7     xyz 
     435   xyz  abc  def
     12    xyz  abc  def
```

Create Table Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    child NUMBER,
    parent NUMBER,
    l1 varchar2(3),
    l2 varchar2(3),
    l3 varchar2(3)
);
```

populate data script:

```
insert into mytable(child, parent, l1, l2, l3)
values (12, 435, 'xyz', null, null);
insert into mytable(child, parent, l1, l2, l3)
values (435, 7, 'xyz', 'abc', 'def');
insert into mytable(child, parent, l1, l2, l3)
values (7, null, 'xyz', null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the connect by to get the proper order.
You can get the last non null value by using the last value ignore nulls clause.

```
  SELECT child, parent,
 last_value(l1) ignore nulls over (
           order by level rows between unbounded preceding and current row
         ) l1,
 last_value(l2) ignore nulls over (
           order by level rows between unbounded preceding and current row
         ) l2,
 last_value(l3) ignore nulls over (
           order by level rows between unbounded preceding and current row
         ) l3
      FROM mytable
      START WITH child = 7
      CONNECT BY PRIOR child = parent
```

here is the fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b36736/10

Answer (score 0):

You could also try below sql. It will work for many cases.

```sql
with cte (CHILD, PARENT, L1, L2, L3,  temp_L1, temp_L2, temp_L3) as (
  select CHILD, PARENT, L1, L2, L3
        , L1 temp_L1, L2 temp_L2, L3 temp_L3
  from mytable
  where mytable.parent is null
  union all
  select t.CHILD, t.PARENT, t.L1, t.L2, t.L3
        , nvl2(t.L1, t.L1, c.temp_L1)temp_L1
        , nvl2(t.L2, t.L2, c.temp_L2)temp_L2
        , nvl2(t.L3, t.L3, c.temp_L3)temp_L3
  from mytable t 
  join cte c on t.parent = c.child
)
search depth first by child set order1
select CHILD, /*PARENT,*/ temp_L1 L1, temp_L2 L2, temp_L3 L3
from cte
order by order1
;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it's working but  giving null level for very last record child=12.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I made an update to my previous answer to cover all the possible cases.